# TextViews in a container

Tags: java, android, textview

Okay so I have 3 TextViews (top, divider, botom) that form a stacked fraction (like 3/4 but the 4 is below the 3 with a horizontal line dividing them).

The problem is the horizontal line... because all the dynamic creation of these elements is done in the onCreate method, I cannot use .getWidth() and .setWidth() to limit the size of the line (it is supposed to be as long as the longest textview, either above or below it).

Now my question is: is it possible to make a container with the three TextViews stacked neatly one above the other, that could be easily added to an existing layout, like a box that would contain the three views and that would function as it's own layout in which I could set the line width, the textview's text align to center etc?

Comment: Yup, add them into some layout; let say in linear-layout. And this linear-layout is the container of them and can be used to put all of them into some other layout or to make invisible all of them or to change location etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was suggested by @Inn_vita, you can add all three to a Linear Layout (as opposed to, say, a Relative Layout) and then treat the layout separately. However, just be careful in that nesting layouts within each other unnecessarily can create overhead and slow your application.

Note, though, that you can change the size of your TextViews programmatically after your `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.

I think this code snippet may help with what you are looking for:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

TextView numerator = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.firstBox);
TextView fractionBar = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.secondBox);
TextView denominator = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.thirdBox);

fractionBar.setWidth(denominator.getWidth());
```

You can do all this after your `setContentView()` within the `onCreate()` method.